# Jenkins pipeline user input - if Abort then action

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have Groovy script for Jenkins with "Verify" (configrmation) step:

```
...
def deploy_prod_verify() {

    stage 'Verify'
    input id: 'Deploy', message: 'Is Blue node fine? Proceed with Green node deployment?', ok: 'Deploy!'

}
...
```

My question is - everything works fine (i.e. - if press "Deploy!" - next stage started).

But - how can I run another function with Jenkins, if "Abort" was pressed?

Now - Jenkins just will abort the current job. I'd like to run another function ("rollback") instead.

I found some documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/), but can't see anything related to "Abort" actions.

I see that "Abort" will execute Ajax call:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('http://<JENKINS HOST>/job/EU-api-staging-build/72/input/Deploy/abort'); return false">Abort</a>
```

And as I understood - there is no way to handle this `Deploy/abort` anyhow.

Answer (score 7):

Following @MaTePe's answer, here's how you can do it:

```
def deploy_prod_verify() {
    stage ('Verify'){
        try {
            input id: 'Deploy', message: 'Is Blue node fine? Proceed with Green node deployment?', ok: 'Deploy!'
            do whatever you need...
        } catch (error) {
            If an error is caught... do this...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to throw some kind of exception or use `throw error` to make sure that the execution of your pipeline will stop. Otherwise the pipeline will continue and your `input` question will be useless (of course excluding cases when this behavior is explicitly desired).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the catchError or try/catch? Haven't tried this myself, and not sure it an exception is thrown when aborted is pressed.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-error-code-error-signal

https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/support-kb-articles/CloudBees-Jenkins-Enterprise/How-to-abort-a-Pipeline-build-if-JUnit-tests-fail.html